# Change variable to uppercase in transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

How can i change a variable to uppercase / lowercase in transacional email?

I need to change the customer name

```
{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}
```

and the store name

```
{{var store.getFrontendName()}}
```

Here's an attachment showing the problem:

[image: email body and inline text]

As you can see, I'm using css to uppercase word *exemplo* but inline preview text doesn't show as uppercase.

Already tried looking for another functions in templates without any success. Is there any documentation about transactional emails language being used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite this file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

To

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

and change below code to queueNewOrderEmail function

```
public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
{
..
..
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = strtoupper($this->getBillingAddress()->getName());
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = strtoupper($this->getCustomerName());
    }
..
..
}
```

Comment: It won't work that way, because i need show as uppercase in email preview, and css only shows when email is opened. I've already done it with css but isn't enough.

Comment: Check my updated answer